# (Parse/Swift) Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm querying for users from Parse, and getting the following warning:

> Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
>    Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

I set a symbolic breakpoint, and...it's not really revealing anything to me (I'm new to Parse, so that may be part of this). A little bit of searching around has suggested that I use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`, but I already am, so I'm at a loss. Any suggestions are welcome! Here's the problematic area:

```
func loadFemaleUsers() {
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("gender", equalTo: "female")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print("Successfully retrieved: objects")
        for object in objects! {
            if object.objectId != self.currentUser?.objectId {
                if object["confirmedEmail"] != nil {
                    self.userList.addObject(object.objectId!)
                }
                else {
                    print("user \(object.objectId) has not confirmed email")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you have any other code whats so ever that reaches to parse?

Comment: Yes, I just pasted the part that it's giving me the warnings for (am able to successfully log in, etc. and do other Parse queries without this warning). Which other pieces would be useful to share?

Comment: That's where the breakpoint hits?